# Why is my JSON extracting method only showing 1 output?

Tags: android, json, api, parsing, networking

I've been learning the networking part in Android and learnt to parse the JSON responses. Recently, I made an Android app which uses the Google Books API and fetches the response in the form of JSON, for a specific query, an example query is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android
```

This specific query outputs all books having **Android** in their title.

Now, when I wrote the following code, below, which is supposed to output, the Title, Authors' Names, Cost of the book and Page Count of each book, I am either a single response or no responses.

```
private static List<Book> extractFeatureFromJson(String jsonResponse) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonResponse)){
        return null;
    }

    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject baseJSONResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray bookArray =baseJSONResponse.getJSONArray("items");
        for(int i=0;i<bookArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject currentBook = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

            String bookName = volumeInfo.getString("title");

            JSONArray authorsList = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
            String authors = "";
            for(int j=0; j<authorsList.length();j++){
                authors += authorsList.getString(j) + ", ";
            }
            authors.substring(0,authors.length()-3);

            JSONObject saleInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("saleInfo");
            JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");
            double cost = listPrice.getDouble("amount");
            String currencyCode = listPrice.getString("currencyCode");
            currencyCode = currencyCode +" "+ Integer.toString((int)cost);
            int pageCount = volumeInfo.getInt("pageCount");
            Book book = new Book(bookName, authors, currencyCode, Integer.toString(pageCount));

            books.add(book);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the book JSON results", e);
    }

    return books;
}
```

Could anyone please explain me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: While examining the Log results it showed

```
04-02 00:43:11.003 29601-29617/com.example.vanur.booklistapp E/QueryUtils: Problem parsing the book JSON results
org.json.JSONException: No value for listPrice
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
    at com.example.vanur.booklistapp.QueryUtils.extractFeatureFromJson(QueryUtils.java:53)
    at com.example.vanur.booklistapp.QueryUtils.fetchBookData(QueryUtils.java:149)
    at com.example.vanur.booklistapp.BookLoader.loadInBackground(BookLoader.java:30)
    at com.example.vanur.booklistapp.BookLoader.loadInBackground(BookLoader.java:9)
    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Add the full error log. Comes after the "Problem parsing the book..." String. Also add a representative sample of the JSON you are parsing.

Comment: @DataDino the JSON response is what you get when you search for the URL https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android , it was very long, so thought it would be messier pasting it

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
04-02 00:43:11.003 29601-29617/com.example.vanur.booklistapp E/QueryUtils: Problem parsing the book JSON results 
org.json.JSONException: No value for listPrice
```

You were looking for a property `listPrice` that doesn't exist and so JSONObject.getJSONObject() throws an Exception as per documentation.

If you have a field that will sometimes be there and sometimes not use `opt` instead of `get`:

```
saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");
```

vs:

```
saleInfo.optJSONObject("listPrice");
```

API: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Then you'll just have to check the return value for `null` and do any handling you'll need to.